# structure occurring C2148 when compiling

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a very large structure, and it seems to be over the limit, what would be the best way to work this out?

Error Message: **total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes**

structure occurring C2148 when compiling

```
struct listen_instance {
   struct instance_l instance[2000];
};
```

I need all this information contained in struct

Structure code below:

```
struct sk_instance {
    int id;
    int rg[10];
    int num[10];
    int ht;
    int ir;
    int el[10];
    int nt;
    int sl[10];
    int blc[10];
    int cst;
    int cdr;
    int mxc[10];
    int mcst[10];
    int wd[10];
    int dl[10];
    int cd[10];
    int vr[10];
    int cz[10];
    int tj[10];
    int hr[10];
    int kg[10];
    int sr[10];
    int nb[10];
    int cv[10];
    int op[10];
};

struct instance_cl {
    int enable_cl;
};

struct instance_ef {
    int ef_time;
};

struct instance_l {
    struct sk_instance sk[1600];
    struct instance_ef ef[700];
    struct instance_cl cl[250];
};

struct listen_instance {
    struct instance_l instance[2000];
};
```

I use as follows in my code

Example 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   Cfi->lis->instance[t].sk[id].rg[i] = 1;
```

Example 2:

```
Cfi->lis->instance[t].ef[200].ef_time = 1000; // 1000 = 1 second
```

Example 3:

```
Cfi->lis->instance[t].cl[10].enable_cl = 1; // true
```

Comment: I'm asking for C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will simply have to switch to dynamic allocation. You could start with just this:

```
struct listen_instance {
    struct instance_l *instance;
};

struct listen_instance init_listen_instance()
{
    struct listen_instance ret;

    ret.instance = malloc(2000 * sizeof(*(ret.instance)));
    if(!ret.instance) { /* Handle error */ }

    return ret;
}
```

Then you can invoke `struct listen_instance myVar = init_listen_instance();` and then you can use `myVar` the same way with one exception. `sizeof(myVar.instance)` will not yield the same result.

If that's not enough, do the same for other structs too.

```
struct instance_l {
    struct sk_instance *sk;
    struct instance_ef *ef;
    struct instance_cl *cl;
};

struct instance_l init_instance_l()
{
    struct instance_l ret;

    ret.sk = malloc(1600 * sizeof(*(ret.sk)));
    if(!ret.sk) { /* Handle error */ }

    ret.ef = malloc(700 * sizeof(*(ret.ef)));
    if(!ret.sk) { /* Handle error */ }

    ret.cl = malloc(250 * sizeof(*(ret.cl)));
    if(!ret.sk) { /* Handle error */ }

    return ret;
}
```

It can be wise to also write free functions when doing like this. Here is an example.

```
void free_instance_l(struct instance_l x)
{
    free(x.sk);
    free(x.ef);
    free(x.cl);
}
```